# Loading a global module in ECMAScript 6

Tags: ecmascript-6

Some old Javascript libraries directly attach an object to the global scope (no AMD, no UMD, no commonJS).

Is there a nice way to "include" a global module in ECMAScript 6 code?
I'm just aware of the following line:

```
import './globallib.js';
```

And then access the global variable directly.

Example: to load QUnit test function:

```
import 'qunit';
test('my test', function () {
  ok(true, 'QUnit loaded');
});
```

Is this the right way?

PS. I encountered this problem while working with QUnit 1.8 in a project that compiles to ES 5 using Babel and Browserify. In QUnit 2 they're gonna avoid globals. But I have this question in general.

Comment: How do they attach it to the "global scope"? Do they use `window.x = `, `this.x = `, `var x = `, `x = `? All of these mean a different thing once they run as module code.

Comment: What environment are you trying to do this in? Node, browser? browserify, webpack, systemjs?

Comment: @loganfsmyth the browser. It is actually for QUnit.

Answer (score 0):

As far the QUnit exports its methods into window (according [source code](https://github.com/jquery/qunit/blob/master/src%2Fexport.js#L45)), you right, import expression is enough.

But anyway, you can't use raw imports in browsers, so you have to use some preprocessing. Webpack and browserify will work for you, but it would not be so for another build systems.